# Maintaining indentation in a long Ensure-block with algorithmicx-package

Tags: line-breaking, algorithms

I have a long "Ensure-block" in my algorithm. How can I force the second line to be exactly under the first "Text"?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Ensure{Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text}
\State bla
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,lipsum}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setensurelength}{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\algorithmicensure}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@tempdima-1em+\@totalleftmargin}}
\newcommand{\setrequirelength}{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\algorithmicrequire}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\@tempdima-1em+\@totalleftmargin}}
\newcommand{\ensurebox}[1]{%
  \setensurelength%
  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\strut #1\strut}}
\newcommand{\requirebox}[1]{%
  \setrequirelength%
  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\strut #1\strut}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Ensure \ensurebox{\lipsum*[2]}
    \Require \requirebox{\lipsum*[2]}
    \State bla
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the ensure/require blocks inside a `\parbox` of fixed width. The fixed width is determined from the list - yes, an `algorithmic` environment is actually a list - by removing certain components' lengths. The `1em` is meant to simulate a (large) horizontal space, enough to shorten the paragraph block to fit within the margins.